# The multi-part identifier could not be found error when update a table of DB1 from that table in DB2

Tags: sql-server

I have tow databases that one of them has some mistake in a table. so I want to update this table from backup DB. I restored backup DB as DB2 and wrote below query to update wrong data.

```
update [DB1].dbo.payments_made set [DB1].[dbo].[payments_made].[person_id] = [DB2].[dbo].[payments_made].[person_id]
where [DB1].dbo.payments_made.id = [DB2].dbo.payments_made.id
```

But I give

> The multi-part identifier "DB2.dbo.payments_made.id" could not be bound.

error when I run query. How can I do this preferred without curser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a join for this

```
UPDATE NEW 
SET    NEW.person_id = OLD.person_id 
FROM   [DB1].dbo.payments_made NEW 
       INNER JOIN [DB2].dbo.payments_made OLD 
               ON NEW.id = OLD.id
```

This is based on the assumption that your `id` column is unique so that the update based on the join is deterministic(one source row maps to one target row)